# Есть ли возможность работать с проектом в PhpStorm сразу на удалённом компьютере по ssh соединению?

Tags: php, phpstorm, ssh

Мне достаточно проблематично скачивать проекты с удалённого хостинга. Могу ли я настроить PhpStorm для работы сразу с удалённого компьютера по ssh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то это то что Вам нужно: [Running SSH Terminal](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/running-ssh-terminal.html)

Или это: [Editing Individual Files on Remote Hosts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/editing-individual-files-on-remote-hosts.html)

Comment: да спасибо, вторая ссылка это то, что надо

Comment: @Sergey пожалуйста